# submit function not call

Tags: forms

I create a menu , in call back of menu create add content form , add one submit function to it, but the function not  call **NEVER** . where is the problem?

```
 $items['share/%'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'ym_alter_sharing_content',
        //'page arguments' => array(''),
        'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );


function ym_alter_sharing_content($form,$form_state) {
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$nid=arg(1);
$form = node_add('share');
//$form['#submit'][]='ym_alter_sharing_sub';
//array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
//array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
//$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]='ym_alter_sharing_sub';
array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
//return render($form);
return $form;
}


function ym_alter_sharing_sub($form,$form_state){

 //dsm($form_state['values']);
 var_dump($form_state['values']);
 die("kill for debugging");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
$items['share/%'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'ym_alter_sharing_content',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);


function ym_alter_sharing_content($some_arg = NULL) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $form = node_add('share');
  array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
  return render($form);
}


function ym_alter_sharing_sub($form, &$form_state){
  //dsm($form_state['values']);
  var_dump($form_state['values']);
  die("kill for debugging");
}
```

**EDIT:**
Another suggestion:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
$node_type = 'YOURNODETYPE';
$form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = $node_type;
node_object_prepare($node);

$form = drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
return render($form);
```

Comment: I test it now, but not worked :((

Comment: @zhilevan Is submit function not being called or form is not being rendered? (I also updated my answer)

Comment: You probably need to use `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'ym_alter_sharing_sub';`

Comment: @xurshid29 The form rendered correctly, only submit  function not call . I test you updated answer , but also not work. it is some strange

Comment: @Clive yes you're right... I didn't know the structure of the form array.. because I didn't render it to test.

Comment: @Clive master I check your tips but not work `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]='ym_alter_sharing_sub';`  :(

Comment: @zhilevan jsut call `dpm($form)` after `$form = node_add('share')` and you can find where to put the submit element..

Comment: @xurshid29 I test it , I get screenshot and update the question

Comment: @zhilevan I updated my answer.. Because `node_form_submit()` is located under `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']`..

Comment: @xurshid29 , I check it, but not work. really it is some strange !!! tnx for you atention xurshid19

Comment: @Clive what is your idea ,why it not work ?

Comment: @zhilevan I tested `array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');` in `hook_form_alter` and it works fine..

Comment: @xurshid29 yes, I did some work like this 1000 times, but it is some strange, maybe it because I use `$form = node_add('share');` really I dont know, I confused :(

Comment: @zhilevan did you try my second suggestion?

Comment: yes, I tried all of them , `//$form['#submit'][]='ym_alter_sharing_sub';
//array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
//array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
 //$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]='ym_alter_sharing_sub';
array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
  //return render($form);
`

Comment: @zhilevan I mean, did you try this code `module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
$node_type = 'YOURNODETYPE';
$form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = $node_type;
node_object_prepare($node);

$form = drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'ym_alter_sharing_sub');
return render($form);`

Comment: yes,I check it right now, but not work :(( , I am going crazy