# hook_form_FORMID_alter not working

Tags: hooks, forms

```
function send_xml_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    $form["#submit"][] = 'send_xml_edit_account_submit_function';
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form['#submit'], TRUE) . '</pre>');
}

function send_xml_edit_account_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message(t("ahoy"));
}
```

the modules name is `send_xml.module`.

this code `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form['#submit'], TRUE) . '</pre>');` displays

```
Array
(
     [0] => user_profile_form_submit
     [1] => send_xml_edit_account_submit_function
)
```

but this code `drupal_set_message(t("ahoy"));` isnt displaying...

anyone ring a bell?

it's quite annoying to have problems which you cant find the reason why... does anyone experience this before? if yes, would please so kind to share your solutions to me. thank you very much! :)

Comment: take a look at [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99634/submit-function-not-call/99638#99638) discussion and its comments.. Probably, some of higher callback is stopping the process...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
function send_xml_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'send_xml_edit_account_submit_function';
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form['#submit'], TRUE) . '</pre>');
}
```

Try clearing Drupal cache before you see the changes..

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to fix this problem @Anil sagar has aslo gave the right answer. Another approach you can take is :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function send_xml_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
          $form['#submit'][] = 'send_xml_edit_account_submit';
   }
}

function send_xml_edit_account_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    print '<pre>';print_r($form['#submit']);  die;
}
```

Do not use ***function*** keyword in a declaration of **function** on  send_xml_edit_account_submit_**function**

Try it, I tried its works for me.